# Determine if AudioKit.start() needs to be called

Tags: swift, audiokit

Using the [AudioKit](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit) framework, how can I determine if `start()` has already been called? Also, if I have called `start()` during the current application session and I don't call `stop()`, is there a situation where I would need to call `start()` again?

I'm building an app that plays a lot of samples, and I'm trying to avoid calling `start()` multiple times unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through the source I was able to determine you can use the following expression:

```
if !AudioKit.engine.isRunning {
    try? AudioKit.start()
}
```

I'm still curious why calling `AudioKit.start()` does not check whether the engine is already running.

**edit**

I've also found that it's useful to wrap all calls to `AKPlayer.play()` with the following check in order to prevent this crash: `Required condition is false: _engine->IsRunning()`.

```
if AudioKit.engine.isRunning {
    myAKPlayer.play()
}
```